# Не получается обновить страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scala, playframework

Есть html страница с кодом

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var currentID = $('#SelecUserForRemove').val();
console.log("currentID= "+currentID)

  $("#testButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/user/"+currentID,
    success: function () {console.log("testButton")},
    error: function () { alert("Не удалось удалить элемент") }
    });
  });

//работа с option для удаления элемента
  $('#SelecUserForRemove').change(function() {
    currentID = $(this).val();
    console.log(("currentID= "+currentID))
   });
});
</script>
```

в файле routes прописано:

```
GET     /                             controllers.UserController.index
GET/user/:id                       controllers.UserController.remove(id:Int)
```

Метод remove:

```
  def remove(id: Int)() = Action {
    userService.removeUser(id)
    println(userService.findAll().toString())
    Redirect(routes.UserController.index())

  }
```

Запрос уходит и обрабатывается на сервере, но метод Redirect не срабатывает и метод index не срабатывает. Для того чтоб увидеть изменения нужно обновить страницу вручную. Если прописать в адресной строке /users/1 то элемент с id=1 успешно удалится и будет осуществлен переход на index Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` срабатывает:

```
success: function (data) { 
  console.log("testButton success", "data=", data);
},
```

Каким образом обработчик `$.ajax` должен перенаправить Вас на другую страницу?

---

```
success: function (data) { 
  window.location = "/user/index";
},

def remove(id: Int)() = Action {
  userService.removeUser(id)
  //println(userService.findAll().toString())
  //Redirect(routes.UserController.index())
  // здесь надо вернуть какую-нибудь строку, на которую в js проверить параметр `data` 
  return "OK"; 
}
```

Comment: он должен выполнить запрос `url: "/user/"+currentID` -> далее в routes должна быть вызвана `remove(id: Int)` -> а в remove `Redirect(routes.UserController.index())`. i

Comment: @СлаваИванов Чему равно `data` в консоли?

Comment: Простите, не понял вопроса

Comment: @СлаваИванов В моем варианте обработчика `success` я добавил вывод результата ajax-запроса в консоль браузера. Что Вы видите в консоли браузера?

Comment: Пришел HTML код страницы, причем все отработало, переданный id отсутствует в списке и в другом списке его состояние изменилось. Это значит, что все пришло. Спасибо большое

Comment: А как теперь грамотно сделать обновление страницы?

Comment: @СлаваИванов Так. Теперь Вы убедились, что `Redirect ` срабатывает. Осталось уяснить, как работает `ajax`, и как перейти на другую страницу после его завершения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89571/discussion-between---and-igor).